# Do most language learners use a tutor/teacher?

Tags: self-learning, tutoring

I had a language tutor for a number of years and did not progress to fluency.

I've seen that many language learners, once they get convinced that they can learn a new language, go on to learn multiple languages.

I do not have a tutor and the same time spent with them has now passed. I have certainly not progressed as much as I did with them.

**TL;DR:** Do the majority of polyglots use tutors at least at the start or are they self taught?

Comment: Welcome to languagelearning.SE! We prefer to have one question within each question. The one about the majority of polyglots and their tutorial use is an objective on topic question (though maybe difficult to answer). The additional question would be better as a separate question, and could use some more precision: Is having a tutor better than what, or what would one be doing with the tutor?

Comment: Not all tutors/teachers are equal. Some are a better match for a particular student, and some are just better - so it's possible you would have made more progress with a different tutor. I definitely think you need feedback from a native speaker, or at least a high level speaker, and for most people the easiest way to arrange that is to get a tutor.